# JayData incorrect behaviour with WebApi v2 Odata during entity Create with kendoGrid

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, kendo-grid, jaydata, asp.net-web-api-odata

this my Controller:

```
 public class ProductEntityController : EntitySetController<
 ProductEntity, int> 
     { 
         public IQueryable< ProductEntity> Get(ODataQueryOptions< ProductEntity> parameters)
         {
             return productList.AsQueryable();
         }
         public  ProductEntity Create(ProductEntity entity)
         {
             productList.Add(entity);

             return entity;
         } }

//---------------------------------------

this my JS code:



 var context = new $data.initService('/odata');
      context.then(function (db) {

      var dsD = db.ProductEntity.asKendoDataSource();

      grid=  $('#gridD').kendoGrid({
                 dataSource: dsD,
                 filterable: true,
                 sortable: true,
                 pageable: true,
                 selectable: true,
                 height: 400,
                 columns: [
                     { field: 'Name' },
                     { field: 'Created' },
                     { field: 'Index' },
                     { field: 'LargeNum' },
                     { command: ["edit", "destroy", "update"] }
                 ],
                 toolbar: ["create", "save", "cancel"],
                 editable: "inline"

           }).data("kendoGrid");


         }).fail(function (args) {  });
```

//------
when i "Add New Record" or "Save Changes" , two request are sent to the server(GET and then POST).

i have an error :`'result count failed ' at GET Response.`

i found a problem in following code in `kendo.js`:

```
  create: function (options, model) {
     var query = self;
     query.entityContext.onReady().then(function () {
     if (model.length > 1) {
     ..............
     ..........
     }
     else {
     console.dir(ctx.storeToken);
     model[0]
     .innerInstance() // when i comment this line everything is gonna be ok

     .save(ctx.storeToken)
     .then(function () {
     options.success();
     })
     .fail(function () {
     console.log("error in create");
     options.error({}, arguments);
     });
     }
     });
     }
```

why is called `innerInstance()` before save?
how can i fix my problem?
i use `Jaydata 1.3.6` with kendo ui and webApi2 Odata  on MVC 5
please help me

Answer (score 0):

this problem occurred when i changed default value of key Field(Id) in create mode at Client side. JayData send GET request with filter to the server.therefore i had and error because i didn't have this Id on my entity.then send POST new Entity to the server.
conclusion:don't have permission to edit your key in kendoGrid and handle it at server.